# His voice is so monotone that it lulls me to sleep every time I hear it

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I've come across [this](https://www.eslpod.com/website/show_podcast.php?issue_id=6284178) sentence.Do you think it is grammatically correct ?For me it seems as if there are two unnecessary/redundant "it"s in this sentence.Because we should not use the subject of a relative clause again in the same relative clause.

> His voice is so monotone that **it** lulls me to sleep every time I hear
>   **it**.

It was supposed to be :

> His voice is so monotone that lulls me to sleep every time I hear.

or

> His voice that lulls me to sleep every time I hear is so monotone.

or

> His voice, which lulls me to sleep every time I hear, is so monotone.

On the other hand, because relative clause does not place next to the thing( here 'his voice') it refers to should we use another subject pronoun here.Which kind of relative clause is this?

Comment: The sentence needs to include both "it"s for it to make sense. This is very obvious to a native English speaker, and I find it interesting that you think it's grammatically incorrect (or redundant). I don't have enough knowledge to explain why they need to be there, but I will upvote you.

Comment: I found [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEB6_WBXAPI) which may be related (I can't watch it right now, I'm at work).

Comment: @nanny thank you for the link.I've watched it  but I am not sure if they exactly the same subject.

Comment: Google Books confirms my intuition that in *adjectival* contexts like this, [*monotonous voice*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22monotonous+voice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is several times more common than [*monotone voice*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22monotone+voice%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Monotone is a noun, I would expect *"His voice is so monotonous that it lulls me to sleep every time I hear it."* ("his voice lulls me to sleep, because it has monotone qualities") or *"His voice is a monotone. Those lull me to sleep every time."* ("monotones lull me to sleep")

Comment: Good question!  But there are no relative clauses here.

Comment: @snailboat I was about to ask that. Do you think it is a sentence with 'subordinating conjunction'. If so, how about my sentences?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree entirely that *monotonous* is the adjective. But one problem with its use is that it has developed a life and career of its own. Nobody thinks of its literal sense any longer, so much as the fact that the speech was simply monotonous (boring). So I believe there is a role for *monotone* to express the literal fact of a single-toned voice. But I would always use it as a noun, as in *his voice was a monotone*.

Comment: @WS2: Indeed. Except that in OP's exact context changing from an adjective to a noun also requires us to change ***so***, giving *his voice was **such a** monotone*